# How Can I stop gwt's embedded server

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jetty

While developing an application using gwt in ecliplse crashed.
Now the server is running on the port 8888 I'm unable to stop it. 
Nothing is showing in the console but I can access the application from the browser. How can I kill the instance of this embedded server?

Comment: Give please more information. Screenshot of browser for example.

Comment: If I understand your question you want to kill the jetty server which is running after eclipse crash.  If so you can get the list of java processes running back group using JDK jps command.  It gives the list of java processes and their process IDs.  You can kill the respective one using Task manager.

Comment: the rough way under linux (note you might also kill other running java processes): ``killall -s 9 java``

Comment: you can also use 'jps -l' to get a list of the java processes

Comment: thanks 'jps -l'  solved the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @jesse  said in the comments 'jps -l' is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you can do this from the "Development mode" view.
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqZaC.png)